# Could someone give a simple non-convex function with 3d plot similar to the one shown below?

Tags: optimization

I'm trying to make a 3d plot that is non-convex. I googled a little bit but didn't find a non-convex function that is as easy to understand as the mean squared error.

I know the [mean squared error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error) is defined as

${\displaystyle \operatorname {MSE} ={\frac {1}{n}}\sum _{i=1}^{n}(Y_{i}-{\hat {Y_{i}}})^{2}.}$

which is a non-convex function, with 2d plot similar to the one shown below.

[image]

What about 3d plot. Could someone give a simple non-convex function with 3d plot similar to the one shown below?

[image]

I also tried [Stochastic gradient Langevin dynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_Langevin_dynamics)

[image]

which involves too much things to understand for me

Answer (score 2):

On this page:

http://infinity77.net/go_2021/scipy_test_functions.html#scipy-test-functions-index

And subsequent pages you can find hundreds of 3D representations of non-convex, multi-modal functions.

I am not clear why you think that a 2D representation of the mean square function has to look like the picture you posted. That might be one *specific* example of how it might look, but by no means the MSE function has to be multi-modal: the shape of the MSE is a function of the underlying model you are using, and does not depend on the fact that it is a sum of squares.